# Pyspark udf function error in lambda function

Tags: lambda, error-handling, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have written a udf function below and it throws me an error. Please help.

Below is my dataset;

```
df1 = sqlContext.range(0, 1000)\
 .withColumn('normal1',func.abs(10*func.round(randn(seed=1),2)))\
 .withColumn('normal2',func.abs(100*func.round(randn(seed=2),2)))\
 .withColumn('normal3',func.abs(func.round(randn(seed=3),2)))

df1 = df1.withColumn('Y',when(df1.normal1*df1.normal2*df1.normal3>750, 1)\
       .otherwise(0))
```

udf function below:

```
from pyspark.sql import types as T
balancingRatio=0.8
calculateWeights = udf(lambda d:(1 * balancingRatio) if d==0 else (1 * (1.0 -   balancingRatio)),T.IntegerType())
weightedDataset = df1.withColumn('classWeightCol', calculateWeights('Y'))
weightedDataset.show()
```

It takes some time and throw me an error;

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o670.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 
in stage 25.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 
25.0 (TID 427, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Python worker failed to connect back.
```

What might be the problem? 
Thank you.

A simple example on internet that I found is not working also

```
maturity_udf = udf(lambda age: "adult" if age >=18 else "child", 
 T.StringType())
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1}])
df.withColumn("maturity", maturity_udf(df.age)).show()
```

Not: I got python 3.7.1 and spark 2.4

Comment: What is `T.IntegerType()` exactly? shouldn't be just `IntegerType()`?

Comment: from pyspark.sql import types as T

Comment: What is your pyspark version?

Comment: my spark version is 2.4

Comment: It seems some version issues. try installing version 2.3 and try again.

Comment: you might be right but did you try and it works for you?
My spark version is 2.4
Python version is 3.7.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184176/discussion-between-melik-and-ali-azg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable fork safety by setting the `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY` variable to `YES` This solved the issue for me.

```
import os
os.environ['OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY'] = 'YES'
```